# Resize Canvas Rectangle with Animation in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to resize my rectangle with animation. I'm using canvas to draw the rectangle.

Is there any solution for animation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to make your Rectangle bigger or smaller?

Comment: It may be anything. i'll change the height and width

Comment: You do not have any drawable or imageView to animate?

Comment: you need to use ScaleAnimation. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html